# Como criar essa expressão regular?

Tags: regex

Preciso de uma expressão regular que aceite apenas `[`, `]`, `-` e `letras` e `números` para ser usada da seguinte forma:

#### Regras

- O primeiro caractere é o `[`, depois vem letras números e o `-` e termina com `]`.
- O primeiro e último caractere dentro dos colchetes não pode conter `-`.
- O conteúdo dentro dos colchetes não pode ser apenas números.

#### Exemplos

1. [Primeiro-Exemplo]
2. [Segundo-Exemplo-Valido]
3. [3-Exemplo-Valido]
4. [Evento-4]

Comment: Que linguagem de programação estás a usar?

Comment: Estou usando c#, mas pretendo usar também em PHP @Sergio

Comment: Á partida isto deveria dar, testa https://regex101.com/r/zQ1oD5/1 Se fôr isso posso juntar uma resposta a explicar.

Comment: Está ótimo, só um detalhe que esqueci de comentar, até atualizei a pergunta: o primeiro e ultimo caractere dentro dos colchetes não pode ser o traço. E também o conteúdo dentro dos colchetes não pode ser apenas números. Mas tá ótimo, se quiser explicar, já marco como resolvida @Sergio :)

Comment: Há alguma regra de quantos `-` há em cada string?

Comment: Não, pois o `-` vai ser apenas para separação das palavras, se o usuário desejar. Mas não é obrigatório, pois, pode conter coisas como [Valido] @Sergio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podes usar assim: `/^\[[\w][\w\-]*[\w]+\]$/`
([exemplo online](https://regex101.com/r/eW6vC0/1))

O que a regex faz:

- `^` indica o inicio da string
- `\[` indica o próprio caractere `[`, escapado para não ser intrepretado como lista
- `[\w]+` aceita numeros e letras. Uma ou mais vezes
- `[\w\-]` o mesmo que a anterior mais os caracteres `_` e `-`, zero ou múltiplas vezes.
- `[\w]+` coloco esta classe de novo mas sem o `\-` para garantir que o ultimo caractere antes do `]` final não é um `-`.
- `\]` indica o próprio caractere `]`
- `$` indica o fim da string

Se quiseres impedir que tenha somente numeros e o separador `-` podes fazer uma verificação com o `negative lookahead` que no fundo é outra regex com o que não é permitido. Nesse caso ficaria assim: `/^(?!^\[[\d\-]+\]$)\[[\w][\w\-]*[\w]+\]$/`, onde `(?!xxx)` é o que indica essa verificação negativa.

([exemplo online](https://regex101.com/r/yR4jM8/1))

Comment: Excelente, era isso que eu precisava. Muito obrigado, Sergio!

Comment: @ZackMorgan ótimo! Fico contente de ter ajudado.

Comment: @Sergio só lembrando que essas regex não contemplam o segundo requisito. Fora isso a resposta esta otima :D

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert bem visto, só tinha verificado o fim da string. Corrigi, obrigado.